# How to apply patches that are created in core-dev

Tags: 8, version-control

Noob here. I'm trying to apply patches to my website, but it's keeps skipping because the version of the patch is for DEV. For example, I want to apply a patch to Core like this issue: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2579343.

How should I apply patches that are in core-dev?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the patch weren't already committed, you would need to reroll the desired patch against your Drupal Core version. This can be done by cloning the git repository of Drupal Core and generating a patch against the relevant revision of your version of Drupal.

The Drupal Core git repository can be found at https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/git-instructions

See [Making a patch](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/git/using-git-to-contribute-to-drupal/making-a-patch) on how to create a patch.

However in this case we can see that the issue has already been marked as "Fixed" and the patch of [comment #19](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2579343#comment-11499883) was committed, so if you are on Drupal Core `8.1.x` or up, you should already have the changes from that patch on your Drupal site.

Comment: Thanks for your help Baikho. I guess I'm still having issues rolling back my d7_fields. I'm using D8.9.11 right now. Thanks for your help. Going to make a new post on how to add a new value in value list.